# Extracting chunk from sentence

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, nlp, nltk

I am trying to extract a chunk from a sentence based on a pattern sequence.

```
import re
import spacy           
nlp = spacy.load('en')
s = "His name is Robinson."
doc = nlp(s)
pattern = re.compile(r'(<PRP$|POS>+<RB.?>)*(<JJ.?>)*(<NN.?|VBG|VBN>+<VB.? 
|MD|RP>+)')
for chunk in doc:

   if(re.search(pattern,chunk.tag_)):
       print(chunk, chunk.tag_)
```

The chunk acquired through this should be is "His name is"

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following line of code,

re.search(r"His name is (.*)", s).group(1)

To change it to pattern sequence,

pattern = "His name is (.*)"
re.search(pattern,s).group(1)

Comment: Every time sentence will be changed and so does chunk, and I want to implement this using pattern sequence which I have used in my code

Comment: I tried this
pattern = "His name is (.*)"
re.search(pattern,s).group(1)
It gives 'Robinson.' as output although the chunk should be "His name is" based on sequnce

Comment: Change group(1) to group.(0)

Comment: It returns same string "His name is robinson".
I want to extract by pos tag sequence.
If i run this  
re.search(pattern,s).group(0)
It give me attribute error